# La synthèse et l'essai argumentatif

Tags: ressources

Bonjour à tous,

J'ai besoin de votre aide/conseil.
Maintenant, je me prépare pour passer l'épreuve de DALF C1 et je me suis arrêté sur un problème avec la production écrite. On me demande de rédiger une synthèse et un essai argumentatif. Franchement, je n'ai pas la moindre idée comment le faire. Chez moi on n'apprend pas cela, donc, je n'en sais rien.
J'ai déjà beaucoup cherché sur l'internet, mais j'ai trouvé seulement des conseils généraux, qui m'ont donné quelques idées, mais.. Ce dont j'ai le plus besoin, ce sont des exemples bien faits (je n'en ai même pas trouvé des mal faits).
Est-ce que quelqu'un pourrait me dire où je pourrais en trouver? Même des manuels sur le sujet seraient vraiment très utiles.

Answer (score 6):

Ceci n'est pas vraiment une question de langue française mais comme il n'y a pas l'équivalent de [writers](https://writers.stackexchange.com/) pour le français, je vais donner des pistes sous forme de sites ressources.

La première chose à faire est de regarder des exemples de sujets donnés les années passées. On peut en trouver sur le [site du CIEP](http://www.ciep.fr/dalf/exemples-sujets). Cliquer sur `DALF C1 Exemple 1` et `DALF C1 Exemple 2`. Les deux documents comportent des exemples pour toutes les épreuves de l'examen, dont les deux qui vous intéressent.

Ensuite il existe de nombreux sites de FLE (Français Langue Étrangère) qui donne soit des conseils, soit des exemples.

- Faire un essai argumentatif : [cette fiche](http://fle-c1.blogspot.fr/2009/11/faire-un-essai-argumentatif.html) donne les règles à respecter pour rédiger l'essai argumentatif dans le cadre du DALF C1.
- L'essai argumentatif : [cette fiche](https://fr.scribd.com/document/122328881/L-essai-argumentatif) donne les critères d'évaluation pour cet exercice.
- Essai argumenté (C1) sur [site de l'Institut français de Milan](https://sites.google.com/site/passetondalf/methodes-et-techniques/essai-argumente-c1). Basique.
- Synthèse de documents (C1) sur le [site de l'Institut français de Milan](https://sites.google.com/site/passetondalf/methodes-et-techniques/synthese-de-documents-c1). Basique.
- Synthèse pour le DALF C1. [Des conseils](http://www.agirenfrancais.com/fle/synthese-pour-le-dalf-c1/).
- Exemples de synthèse pour le DALF C1 français | se préparer à l'épreuve. [Tout est dans le titre](https://lefrancaisentrequatzyeux.blogspot.fr/2017/01/exemples-de-synthese-pour-le-dalf-c1.html) et ne pas négliger les liens vers d'autres ressources en bas de page. Très bon site pour préparer le DALF.

Je n'ai fait qu'une petite sélection, vous en trouverez beaucoup d'autres en faisant les recherches :
-  DALF C1 "essai argumentatif".
- DALF C1 synthèse.

Il est très difficile de trouver sur internet des corrigés types de ces deux épreuves qui sont des épreuves de rédaction. Je peux vous proposer [ici](https://flealeon.wordpress.com/2011/11/28/exemple-depreuve-de-delf-c1/) pour la synthèse, pour l'essai je n'ai trouvé que [ceci](http://www.etudier.com/sujets/essai-argument%C3%A9-epreuve-dalf-c1/0), ce site est sur inscription (gratuit semble-t-il) je n'ai pas pu évaluer la qualité des documents proposés.
Voir aussi cet [extrait de manuel](http://widget.editis.com/cle/9782090381795#page/24/mode/1up) qui comporte des propositions de corrigés de production écrite (voir pages 165 +)

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Oui, les ressources, c'est ce qu'il me faut. Je n'ai malheureusement pas réussi à les trouver. Les conseils et les articles de façon "comment faire" sont courants, mais au contraire les examples, les synthèses déjà rédigé,  il y en a trop peu. À cause de cela je n'ai jamais vu ni la synthèse ni l'essai argumentatif. Auriez-vous, par hasard, un conseil où trouver cela? Des liens, que vous m'avez donné le dernier est le plus proche à cela.

Comment: @J.Blaha Avez-vous télécharger les deux documents que je vous signale en premier et contenants des sujets entièrement rédigés sur le site du CIEP ?  Il y a des exemples, attention il y a deux sujets pour chaque puisque le candidat doit choisir un domaine (lettres et sciences humaines ou sciences). Ensuite ce qu'il faut c'est de l'entraînement et quelqu'un qui vous corrige des devoirs. Suivez-vous des cours ? J'ai ajouté dans ma réponse un paragraphe concernant des corrigés types de ce genre d'épreuves.